# Find x-intercept and y-intercept of a loop in R

Tags: r

How can I find x-intercept and the y-intercept (all four) of a loop with `R`?

```
# this will generate an example dataframe mydf
x <- sin(seq(0,2*pi,0.2) + rnorm(1))
y <- cos(seq(0,2*pi,0.2) + rnorm(1))

mydf <- data.frame(x,y)
plot(mydf)
abline(h=0)
abline(v=0)
```

[image: impression of the loop]

At the moment I try around with two similar functions, that divide in north/south/east/west
and look for the closest point to the axis. This is inefficient and not precise, because the point might be far away.

```
getYintercept <- function(mdf){
  R1 <- mdf$y[which.min(subset(mdf, y>0)$y)] # north
  R2 <- mdf$y[which.min(subset(mdf, y<0)$y)] # south
  return(rbind(R1,R2))
}
```

Thus I want to interpolate (`predict`, `approx`) this point. 
How can this be solved most elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `approxfun` solution:

```
intercepts <- function(x,y) {
  x.s <- approxfun(x[y<=0], y[y<=0])(0)
  x.n <- approxfun(x[y>=0], y[y>=0])(0)
  y.w <- approxfun(y[x<=0], x[x<=0])(0)
  y.e <- approxfun(y[x>=0], x[x>=0])(0)

  list(x.s, x.n, y.w, y.e)
}
```

Here, `x.s` is the `x` value of the south y-intercept, and so on.

Comment: Nice solution. It works well. Is it better to return a list then a data.frame in general? And how does approxfun select the values? The `?approxfun` page says the linear mode is standard so it should not use all north values...

Comment: ahhh... it uses two consecutive values... now I understand it.

Comment: That's correct, linear interpolation between consecutive values is the default mode.  Lists are a convenient way of returning multiple values from a function.  A data frame would work just as well, but I don't see any advantage.  For this function, even a vector could be returned (as each return value has length 1).